# Using typecast for (void *) in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, tooltip

i am using the addToolTipRect: method to set a tooltip rect

```
- (NSToolTipTag)addToolTipRect:(NSRect)aRect owner:(id)anObject userData:(void *)userData
```

and method stringForToolTip: to obtain string value for tooltip.

```
- (NSString *)view:(NSView *)view stringForToolTip:(NSToolTipTag)tag point:(NSPoint)point userData:(void *)data
```

However the above functions work fine if i send something like

```
[self addToolTipRect:someRect owner:self userData:@"Tool tip string"];
```

But doesn't work when i send the following string. Error: BAD_ACCESS

```
const NSString * tooltipStr = @"Tool tip string";
[self addToolTipRect:someRect owner:self userData:tooltipStr];
```

In both the cases, the stringForToolTip looks like:

```
- (NSString *)view:(NSView *)view stringForToolTip:(NSToolTipTag)tag point:(NSPoint)point userData:(void *)data
  {
     id obj = (id)data;
     NSString * str=nil;
     if ([obj isKindOfClass:[SomeClass class]]) //This is my system defined class and works fine
     {
         SomeClass * someClassObj = (SomeClass *) data;
          str = someClassObj.title;
     }
     else if([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
         str = (NSString*)obj;
     return str;
  }
```

NOTE: In the stringForToolTip: method I also want to check for some other class example [obj isKindOF:[SomeClass class]] and i don't want to assert that value. The problem here is just in getting the string value by proper cast but I can't figure out how! Please tell me where I am going wrong?

edit:
What should be the right way to get the String value for tooltip in that case? should the point or tag be considered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(void *)` is not an object pointer.

That `@"Tool tip string"` worked was by coincidence based on the fact that is is a compile-time constant with a (essentially) permanent allocation and permanent address.

But in the code:

```
const NSString * tooltipStr = @"Tool tip string";
[self addToolTipRect:someRect owner:self userData:tooltipStr];
```

`tooltipStr` is an object that is kept in memory by a strong reference (retain count > 0). Since `userData:` does not handle objects it does not make a strong reference (does not increase the retain count) so it is released, will disappear soon becoming invalid.

Notes from the documentation:
The tooltip string is obtained from the `owner`. The `owner` must respond to one of two messages, `view:stringForToolTip:point:userData:` or `description`, use the latter. Note that `NSString` responds to `description` so you can pass an `NSString` for the value of owner. So, what you want is: `[self addToolTipRect:someRect owner:tooltipStr userData:NULL];`. There is still an issue that something must hole a strong reference to the `NSString` instance.

You can: [self addToolTipRect:someRect owner:@"Tool tip string" userData:NULL];

Probably the best way to go is to pass self as owner and NULL as data and implement the delegate method: view:stringForToolTip:point:userData: in the class.

Comment: What should be the right way to get the String value for tooltip in that case? should the point or tag be considered?

Comment: @SkCoder Read the documentation. I have updated the answer to address your comment.